# glfw drag window is laggy initially on macOS

Tags: macos, go, opengl, glfw

I just created a window using glfw and runs on macOS. The problem is: If I drag the window and move around, the movement of the window is super laggy initially, but get smooth later. The issue does not appear on Linux (Ubuntu). Why and how to fix it?

System: macOS 10.15.7 (19H2)
Code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"

    "github.com/go-gl/gl/v4.1-core/gl"
    "github.com/go-gl/glfw/v3.3/glfw"
)

func init() {
    runtime.LockOSThread()
}

func main() {
    err := glfw.Init()
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Errorf("failed to initialize GLFW: %w", err))
    }
    defer glfw.Terminate()

    glfw.WindowHint(glfw.Resizable, glfw.False)
    glfw.WindowHint(glfw.ContextVersionMajor, 4)
    glfw.WindowHint(glfw.ContextVersionMinor, 1)
    glfw.WindowHint(glfw.OpenGLProfile, glfw.OpenGLCoreProfile)
    glfw.WindowHint(glfw.OpenGLForwardCompatible, glfw.True)

    win, err := glfw.CreateWindow(800, 600, "glfw", nil, nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer win.Destroy()
    win.MakeContextCurrent()
    if err := gl.Init(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    win.SetTitle(fmt.Sprintf("%s", gl.GoStr(gl.GetString(gl.VERSION))))
    gl.ClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)

    for !win.ShouldClose() {
        gl.Clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        win.SwapBuffers()
        glfw.PollEvents()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try `WaitEvents()` instead of `PollEvents`, and consider using: `SwapInterval(1)` - redrawing as fast as possible without regard to vsync, etc., is the GPU equivalent of a busy-wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not Go related. An example is written in C also reproduces the problem:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

The short answer is: Use `glfwWaitEvents` on macOS.

The long answer is that glfwPollEvents processes events if there are any. Otherwise, it returns immediately. That means the (trivial) program is clearing the screen over and over again as quickly as possible, consuming a lot of CPU time. The alternative, glfwWaitEvents, blocks if there are no events waiting, consuming little or no CPU time. Arguably a program using a lot of CPU should not cause the window to lag, but that's really down to the operating system and how it allocates resources.

As for which of the two functions to use, it depends entirely on what else we want our program to do. If we only want to react to user input and nothing else, glfwWaitEvents is probably the way to go. If we want to do other things within the event loop, glfwPollEvents is probably more appropriate, especially if we want to redraw the window contents independently of user input.

Aside: glfwSwapInterval(1) will probably also avoid the lag, as it will cause glfwSwapBuffers to block for some milliseconds, again giving the CPU a rest.